# Filter packets by mac address and "EAP" in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

Is there a way to filter packets by mac address and "EAP" protocol using scapy in python?
this is my sniff command line:

```
sniff(iface="mon0",prn=lambda x: x.summary())
```